# Can this be solved with a line sweep algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

Edit: Now I think this is a sweep line problem. (see update2 at the bottom)

In this problem we are given `N` objects and `M` constraints. (`N` can be `200k`, `M` can be `100k`). Each object is either black, or white. Each constraint is in the form `(x, y)` and means that in the range of objects `x..y`, there is *exactly one* white object; the rest are black. We would like to determine the maximum number of white objects that can exist, or if it isn't possible to satisfy the constraints.

I observe that if a constraint is fully contained in another, the inner constraint will dictate where a white object can be placed. Also, if there are several non-intersecting constraints contained within another, it should be impossible since it violates the fact that there can only be *one* white object per constraint. The algorithm should be fast enough to run under 2-3 seconds.

Update: One of the answers mentions the exact cover problem; is this a specialized instance that isn't NP-complete?

Update2: If we change each constraint into a *begin* and *end* event, and sort these events, could we just systematically sweep across these events and assign white objects?

Comment: "Also, if there are several non-intersecting constraints contained within another, it should be impossible since it violates the fact that there can only be one white object per constraint." I don't follow; when are constraints both non-intersecting and contained within another? I assumed by "contained within another" you meant of the form (x,y) (u,v) where x <= u < v <= y, but the intersection then clearly is (u,v). If that is the case, this kind of nested constraint can be solved by placing one white vertex in the innermost constraint and the coloring the rest of the outermost const. black.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant and now that I think of it, do you think just greedily determining the white objects by processing/simulating something could just work?

Comment: This is perhaps a better match for http://cs.stackexchange.com...

Comment: This doesn't look like a graph problem at all. Where are the edges?

Comment: Hm I'm not certain about greedy, it does seem to me that after reducing the constraint system, you should be able to do that and apply combinatorial methods. Maybe it'll help to think about reduction rules you can derive for the constraint system. For example, assume you have three constraints (a,c) (b,f) (d,e) with a<= b <= c < d <= e <=f. You then know that you can reduce (a,c) to (a,b) because the nested constraint (b,f) (d,e) will force you to color (b,c) black. That's where I would start. I think there should be a couple more reduction rules than that example illustrates.

Comment: If you do go the route of reducing the constraints, you'll have to think of rules for a) nesting and b) intersections, which really are just full intersections. To find the constraints for which you'll have to apply reduction rules, you might want to look at interval trees.

Comment: @n.m. I was thinking if one  constraint is fully contained within another, we could draw an edge between the constraints.

Comment: @G.Bach Also I just noticed that if two constraints intersect, the white object has to lie within the intersection. Edit: Actually this isn't true, ignore me. It only works if it's fully contained.

Comment: @ZheyangShen Yes that is something you'll have to deal with; if two sets A and B defined by two constraints intersect such that A\B and B\A are non empty, you'll either have to place one white vertex in A∩B or one white vertex each in A\B and B\A. This is something reduction rules would have to deal with, or - if you choose not to reduce those rules and instead deal with it later on combinatorially - you'll have to consider while calculating the number of possibilities.

Comment: What this does however hint at is that you will have to expect an exponential number of combinations in the general case.

Comment: @G.Bach There exists a solution that runs under the time limit, which is 3 seconds. Maybe we can binary search on the answer and greedily place the white objects?

Comment: @G.Bach I'm also thinking about a line sweep algorithm too.

Comment: @n.m. if, for every pair in each constraint you add an edge, wouldn't this be a graph coloring? Although graph coloring is NP complete.

Answer (score 2):

You problem can be expressed as an [exact cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover): the constraint intervals form the set to be covered, and each white object covers those constraint intervals which it falls inside of.  Your problem, then, is to find a subset of the white objects which covers each constraint interval exactly once.

Exact cover problems in general are NP-complete, although that obviously doesn't necessarily mean that any specific subset of them are.  However, there nonetheless exist algorithms, such as [Knuth's Algorithm X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X) (as implemented by [dancing links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links)) that can solve *most* such problems quite efficiently.

It's possible that the one-dimensional structure of your problem might also allow more straightforward specialized solution methods.  However, Algorithm X is a very good general tool for attacking such problems.  (For example, the fastest [sudoku solvers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms) typically use something like it.)

Comment: This is interesting but I can't find a non-NP-complete solution to this problem.

Comment: @ZheyangShen Where'd you find that problem? If you know there's an efficient solution, I assume you know who solved this?

Comment: @G.Bach Don't know what the source is. It's a practice problem for my school's ICPC team. If I knew the answer, I wouldn't be asking it here :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a (point)-sweep algorithm. This one is sort of inelegant, but I think it works.

First, sweep for nested intervals. Process begin and end events in sorted order (tiebreakers left to you) and keep a list of active intervals not known to contain another interval. To handle a begin event, append the corresponding interval. To handle an end event, check whether the corresponding interval `I` has been removed. If not, remove `I` and all of the remaining intervals `J` before `I` from the list. For each such `J`, append two intervals whose union is the set difference `J \ I` to a list of blacked out intervals.

Second, sweep to contract the blacked out intervals.  In other words, delete the objects known to be black, renumber, and adjust the constraints accordingly. If an entire constraint is blacked out, then there is no solution.

Third, sweep to solve the problem on what are now non-nested intervals. The greedy solution is provably optimal.

Example: suppose I have half-open constraints [0, 4), [1, 3), [2, 5). The first sweep creates blackouts [0, 1) and [3, 4). The second sweep leaves constraints [a, c), [a, c), [b, d).* The greedy sweep places white objects at new locations a, c, d (old locations 1, 4, 5).

Illustration of the second sweep:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5  old coordinates
[       )
  [   )
    [     )
**    **     blackouts
  a b   c d  new coordinates
[       )
  [   )
    [     )
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the first step? What if the intervals aren't fully intersecting?

Comment: `I` is always a subinterval of `J`. If `I1` and `I2` overlap but don't nest, nothing happens yet.

Comment: In this case, if they overlap, the interval `I` should always be in the interval `J`, right?

Comment: Wait, I think I get what the first step is going to do. Can you elaborate on the second?

Comment: But if you place the white objects at locations `0` and `2`, you the first constraint `[0, 4)` will have two white objects, right?

Comment: You're comparing two different coordinate systems. The original locations would be 0 and 4.

Comment: Oh. I still don't get how the second sweep creates the 3 intervals listed?

Comment: How are the "new coordinates" assigned? I know you cross out the blacked out regions but why are the numbers `0` and `2` doubled up? Thanks for the help.

Comment: The blacked out regions are supposed to cease to exist.

Comment: If they cease to exist, how did you adjust the original constraint `[0, 4)` to `[0, 2)`? Since the `0` in the first constraint no longer exists after the blackouts.

Comment: You're still confusing the old coordinates with the new coordinates. I've switched the latter to letters.

Comment: My understanding is that the second step readjusts the coordinates of the original 3 constraints, by somehow mapping the original coordinate to a letter. However, in the diagram, the first constraint's left coordinate doesn't coincide with any letter. My question was how did this end up getting converted to `a`? I'm probably overlooking something really obvious...

Comment: Oh... how did the `3` in the second constraint `[1, 3)` get adjusted to a `c` in the new coordinate system? Again, in the diagram it does not coincide with any of the new coordinates.

Comment: Also in your description after the diagram, `a` should correspond to `1`, not `0`.

Comment: So I suppose my overarching question is: how do you map the old coordinates to the new coordinates, if the old coordinate has been blacked out?

Comment: I don't participate on SO for the rep, but as you're sweeping the exactly-1 constraints (original constraints) and the exactly-0 constraints (the black intervals), maintain the total number of objects so far that lie within a black interval. This is the difference between the old and new coordinates for the sweep point (assuming it's not blacked out).